# DNSSEC - DNSKEY RRSIG not updated

Tags: keys, dnssec

Does anybody know why the DNSKEY RRsigs are not re-signed with dynamic update??

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Are you using BIND 9.7?  If you want BIND 9.7 to automatically re-sign a zone after a dynamic update you need to add "auto-dnssec maintain" to the zone file definition.